# Thunderbird reply-to Address

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird 17.0.6 on Windows 7 x64. I use it to manage two e-mail accounts. I wanted to unsubscribe from a mailing list, so I sent an e-mail to an automatic service in order to do so.

I selected the **address that was subscribed** in the from drop-down menu in Thunderbird's "write" window.

Quickly after sending the message, I received an error **on my other e-mail account** saying that I couldn't unsubscribe since that account wasn't subscribed (it's not).

Why does this happen? Why did the mailing list manager interpret my e-mail as sent from *another address than the one chosen in the **from field***?

Note: I didn't edit my `reply-to` account settings.

Comment: Did you double-check in the *Sent* folder?

Comment: Yes, the message appears in both of my sent folders. I can, however, confirm that it didn't actually get sent twice.